# Is "have had" grammatical and natural here?

Tags: grammar

Context: A divorced father has had his son over for a few hours and they ended up having a heated argument that ruined the evening. His ex-wife talks with him two days later. She is angry and says this:

*What happened? Why couldn't you just have had a fun time with him?*

Is this sentence phrased grammatically correct and natural for the context (in particular "have had")?

Comment: It's fine but we don't do corrections here like this.

Comment: There is no problem here.  The sentences are 100% correct, and natural.  What makes you think there is a problem?  Are you having difficulty with the present perfect tense "have had"?

Answer (score 0):

It's grammatically correct. In conversation, I think it would be more natural to say "Why couldn't you just have fun with him?", or "Why didn't you just have fun with him?".